# How can I recursively bzip2 all files that aren't bzipped?

Tags: linux, ssh, recursive, compression

How can I recursively bzip2 all files that do not end with the `.bz2` extension in Linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

find is your friend. I reckon the following ought to do it:

```
find <target_dir> -not -name \*.bz2 -exec bzip2 \{\} \;
```

i.e. if the dir where the files you want to bzip are is /var/log/blah it would be:

```
find /var/log/blah -not -name \*.bz2 -exec bzip2 \{\} \;
```

Comment: It may be faster to use `+` or `xargs` instead of `\;`. It's not necessary to escape the curly braces. POSIX supports `!` for "not".

Comment: Why vote down? Will it not work on the platform specified?

Comment: No clue why the downvote, this is the best (and correct) answer, I use it all the time. I also use xargs though, can't stand the -exec to find. Also consider using -print0 on the find and -0 to xargs to use NULL separation instead of spaces in case the filenames have spaces.

Comment: Unless they're all very small files, xargs is probably premature optimization anyways (the actual compression will take most of the time, not the fork and exec of starting up bzip2 repeatedly)...   But: `find /var/log/blah -not -name \*.bz2 -print0 | xargs -0 bzip2`

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head (sorry, don't have a shell handy to test quoting etc.):

```
for _t in `find . -print |grep -v -E "\.bz$"`; do bzip2 -9 $_t && echo OK $_t || echo FAIL $_t; done
```

This uses find to find all files, grep to strip out the ones with a .bz2 extension and then feed them one at a time into bzip2. I expect some of the quoting is wrong, though - I'd test the bit in the backquotes separately first.

Good luck! You might want to use xz instead, though - it usually compresses better - or even tar everything up and bzip2 or xz instead.

Comment: ... or apparently you can do it all in find. I didn't know it could do '-not' hence the grep etc. here.

Comment: I think the -not in find is only a GNU find option - so I don't think you could use it with most proprietary find commands - but since the question specifies Linux, GNU find is probably OK - your approach is probably more portable.

Comment: POSIX supports `!` for "not". Using a `for` loop will fail for files that have spaces in their names. You should use `find | while read`.

Answer (score 1):

With zsh (`setopt extended_glob` must be on):

```
bzip2 **/^*.bz2(.)
```

`**` recurses in subdirectories; `^*.bz2` matches everything except `*.bz2`; `(.)` restricts to regular files.

With bash 4, if you're ok with ignoring `bzip2`'s complains about being invoked on directories:

```
bzip2 **/!(*.bz2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner. If necessary, install `ifne` first. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

And then:

```
find YOUR_DIR -type f -not -name \*.bz2 -print0 | ifne xargs -0 bzip2
```

This does the same as other answers, but you won't get warning messages about bzip2ing directories, and if there is nothing to `bzip2` anymore, you won't get warning messages about bzip2ing compressed data to a terminal. It also uses `xargs` etc.

YOUR_DIR can have wild cards or multiple dirs, e.g. YOUR*DIR or the like.

Answer (score 0):

In the `fish` console, it's pretty straightforward, and you don't have to worry about pipes and weird backslashes:

```
set files (find *)
for i in $files
    bzip2 $i
end
```